# Convert String to NSDate weird format

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I think my string date is in a weird format, but I have the following code:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(subJson["lastSyncTime"].string!)
```

My subJson["lastSyncTime"].string = `2015-07-30T11:44:37.070`

Not sure what im doing wrong, as Im new to swift. It seems the T in the middle may be messing things up? But the variable "date" = nil

Comment: Why don't you replace the T by a space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z
```

I've tried with your code and it works:

```
let subJson = "2015-07-30T11:44:37.070"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(subJson)
```

Answer (score 2):

the date string is an `ISO 8601` formatted date, so use this format

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend unwrapping it like this

```
if let dateObject = subJson?["lastSyncTime"] as? NSString {

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"
    var dateNSDate: String = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateObject)

}
```